# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Soap API failing

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap

I wanted to get a list of all BUs and Users associated with those BU. For the BU I am using SOAP API as REST does not support it.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">yyy</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>BusinessUnit</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response which i am getting is about token (i am not using token).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:98d322b3-5d9a-4a23-bac6-bab7cbed45eb</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:788a03dc-05e0-4427-9233-c23fd68c03ab</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-4fb1801f-7396-47ab-a421-12ce586ace5f">
                <wsu:Created>2020-06-15T14:12:52Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2020-06-15T14:17:52Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:q0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">q0:Security</faultcode>
            <faultstring>An invalid security token was provided</faultstring>
            <faultactor>https://mc44m84qcn2cdhgywd0dypw57gf8.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</faultactor>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any clue on how to get BU and AccountUsers or making SOAP API work would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't got the authentication setup correct to work with the SOAP API. Have you followed the steps in [this guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/authenticate-soap-api.htm)? The error message suggests it is the same as [this previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272695/authenticating-soap-api-via-usernametoken) which was solved  by following the steps listed.

Comment: @ChandrashekharDautpure Can you verify via comment what the actual fix was?